# Qual a melhor maneira de repetir a mesma query sem copiar e colar?

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho uma query e vou precisar usá-la duas vezes, uma eu vou usar o `fetchCollum` e outra vou usar o `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Dito isso, eu não consigo aplicar um `fetch` e depois aplicar outro `fetch`, por exemplo:

```
$tokenHash = $query->fetchColumn(10);
    if($query->rowCount() === 0 || (hash_equals($tokenHash, $tokenGet) === FALSE)):
        echo 'Token Inválido!';
        header( "refresh:10;url=listarDados.php" );
        exit;
    else:
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ele acaba me retornando como `boolean false`.E para não ter que fazer tudo de novo e simplesmente copiar e colar, existe uma alternativa para repetir a mesma query só que utilizar fetch's diferentes?

Comment: Dá um `fetch()` e armazenar o retorno, depois pegar essa variável resolve? se a consulta for a mesma não tem problema.

Comment: Como que é? não entendi???

Comment: É quase inverter o código da pergunta. Troque o `fetchColumn()` por `fetch()` no começo do código. No if no lugar de passar `tokenHash` passe algo como `$row['campo_a_ser_validado']`.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples é armazenar o resultado da consulta (em `$row`) e usar ele em diversos lugares. `fetch()` vai retornar todos os campos escolhidos na consulta na hora de comparar/manipular basta especificar qual, como no if `$tokenHash` foi trocada por `$row['tokenHash']` (verifique se esse é o nome correto do campo)

```
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($query->rowCount() === 0 || (hash_equals($row['tokenHash'], $tokenGet) === FALSE)){
    echo 'Token Inválido!';
    header( "refresh:10;url=listarDados.php" );
    exit;
}
```

Caso deseje usa o `fetchColumn()` e tenha usado uma consulta preparada basta chamar o méotod `execute()` novamente e fazer o `fetch()`, o código fica dessa forma:

```
$row = $query->fetchColumn(10);
if($query->rowCount() === 0 || (hash_equals($tokenHash, $tokenGet) === FALSE)){
    echo 'Token Inválido!';
    header( "refresh:10;url=listarDados.php" );
    exit;
}else{
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Então @rray, eu pensei em fazer dessa maneira, mas eu gostaria de fazer do jeito que está na pergunta.

Comment: Especificamente fazer um fetch collum e depois um fetch assoc, tem como sem ctrl c crtrl v?

Comment: @user6894456 tem sim :P é como está na minha resposta. Usou o `prepare()` se sim basta chamar novamente o `execute()` e fazer um `fetch()` no else

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado